# RSA and convergents

Tags: pari, pari-gp

I'm trying to do a function in PARI that computes `a^(c*q_t) mod n;` where `c` and `n` are such big numbers, and `q_t` is the denominator of a convergent of `n/c`. This is for RSA purposes. I'd just like to improve this function, so that computer would do it by itself, I mean it would find the `q_t` by itself and discover also the `a` itself. So, it would need two more parameters. I have no idea how to do this.
This is my function:

```
expmod(a,e,m)={
  local(x,y,s,d); x=a; y=1; s=e;
  while(s,d=s%2;s=(s-d)/2;
  if(d,y=(y*x)%m); x=(x*x)%m);
  return(y)}
```

Comment: Please, improve your question. Your code has input parameters `a`, `e`, and `m` while your text defines another variables `c`, `q_t`, and `n`. I guess you want to implement RSA encoder/decoder in PARI/GP. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is that! @PiotrSemenov

Answer (score 0):

PARI has a built in type `Mod(a,m)` that keeps track of the modulus through exponents.

```
lift(Mod(a,m)^e)
```